# Libgdx: при отрисовке sprite элементов массива ошибка on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Подскажите такой вопрос:
Упаковал текстуры ,подключил атлас и собственно инициализировал изображения,но по нажатию на стар, вылетает приложение с ошибкой:
 **on a null object reference**
и ругается на эту строку  **game.batch.draw(sprite, raindrop.x, raindrop.y);**

```
  r1 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r1"));
    r2 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r2"));
    r5 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r5"));
    r10 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r10"));
    r20 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r20"));
    r50 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r50"));
    r100 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r100"));
    r200 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r200"));
    r500 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r500"));
    k1 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("k1"));
    k2 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("k2"));
    k5 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("k5"));
    k10 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("k10"));
    k20 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("k20"));
    k50 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("k50"));

Sprite  bucketImage, r1, r2, r5,
        r10, r20, r50, r100, r200, r500, k1, k2, k5, k10, k20, k50;
```

необходимо создать массив Sprite этих изображений , а потом
отрисовывать на экране так:

```
game.batch.draw(bucketImage, bucket.x, bucket.y);

    for (Rectangle raindrop : raindrops) {
        for (Sprite sprite : sprites) {
            game.batch.draw(sprite, raindrop.x, raindrop.y);
        }
    }

private void spawnRaindrop() {
    Rectangle raindrop = new Rectangle();
    raindrop.x = MathUtils.random(0, 800 - 64);
    raindrop.y = 480;
    raindrop.width = 64;
    raindrop.height = 64;
    raindrops.add(raindrop);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}
    game.batch.end();
```

spawnRaindrop() создает новый Rectangle, устанавливает его в случайной позиции в верхней части экрана и добавляет его в raindrops массив.

Comment: А старый добрый ArrayList<Sprite> Вам не подходит?

Comment: @Виктор Евлампьев
а как потом выводить game.batch.draw ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как насчёт:

```
Sprite[] sprites=new Sprite[] {r1, r2, r5, ...};
...
for (Rectangle raindrop : raindrops) {
    for (Sprite sprite : sprites) {
        game.batch.draw(sprite, raindrop.x, raindrop.y);
    }
}
```

Пойдёт?

Comment: конечно,буду пробовать

Comment: вылетает с ошибкой

Comment: А какая ошибка? Если используешь Android Studio, внизу есть вкладка "Android Monitor" (она должна активироваться при запуске проги на устройстве или эмуляторе), там всё что выделено красным это ошибка (обычно начинается с "E/").